# Mostly By Way of Emphasis

Tags: rebus

Here's a simple one (clue in the title):

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it is:

> First and foremost

Comment: haha - I said it was an easy one!  Thanks!  You are a good guesser.

Comment: @BGM why is there an arrow towards the fourth 'most' then?

Comment: To indicate which `mosts` are noteable.  Do you think there's a better way?

Comment: Possibly bold them or put 1. beside the first 'most' like a list (the second option might give away too much though).